# Float div elements beneath eachother

Tags: html, css

I want to have the div elements beneath each other. So 1, 2 and 3 are OK, 4 beneath 3.

Image: http://img42.com/DZIeu+

The HTML has to be the same because a user can add a new div. (max of 8 div's, so the oldest div goes away). Because of the browser support of nth I don't want to use Absolute positioning or fixed width.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="nwsgal">
    <div class="nwsitem">1</div>
    <div class="nwsitem">2</div>
    <div class="nwsitem">3</div>
    <div class="nwsitem">4</div>    
    <div class="nwsitem">5</div>
    <div class="nwsitem">6</div>
    <div class="nwsitem">7</div>
    <div class="nwsitem">8</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nwsgal{
background:#FAFAFA;
width:100%;
height:40%;
min-height:250px;
display:block;
position:relative;  
overflow:hidden;
vertical-align:top;
}

.nwsitem{
    background:#999;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

.nwsitem:nth-child(3), .nwsitem:nth-child(4){width:25%; height:50%;}
.nwsitem:nth-child(5), .nwsitem:nth-child(6), .nwsitem:nth-child(7), .nwsitem:nth-child(8){width:12.5%; height:50%;}
.nwsitem:nth-child(odd){background:#FDFDFD;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntxhbj43/

Any ideas, js/css solution?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're after. Can you elaborate, and maybe add an image of what you want?

Comment: Try attaching an illustration image to your question. That will go along way.

Comment: I Can't post images yet, so I posted a link to the image.

Comment: Look into `flexbox` it might have a solution you're looking for.  If you don't want to use absolute positioning nor javascript, you are going to have to use next-gen CSS.  Floating does not work the way you want it to because it was intended to wrap text around block elements

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in a container.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nwsgal">
        <div class="nwsitem">1</div>
        <div class="nwsitem">2</div>
        <div class="nwsitemwrap">
            <div class="nwsitem">3</div>
            <div class="nwsitem">4</div>    
        </div>
        <div class="nwsitemwrap">
            <div class="nwsitem">5</div>
            <div class="nwsitem">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nwsitemwrap">
            <div class="nwsitem">7</div>
            <div class="nwsitem">8</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need a bit of additional styling for the wrappers and children of the wrappers:

```
.nwsitemwrap { float: left; width: 25%; }
.nwsitemwrap > .nwsitem { width: 100%; float: none; }
```

**EDIT** And here's a [functional fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntxhbj43/1/). To make it "dynamic" we'd need to know how you want to layout the items on certain cases.

Comment: giorgio hit it just right.  You need to break out the columns first then within columns you can stack items.  Depending on how much of this you need to do, you might want to build a proper [CSS grid system](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/)

Comment: I have a feeling this won't work for the OP because I'm sure these are going to be dynamic.  Great solution otherwise

Comment: I don't want to have extra HTML because it works like a newsitemtemplate in an CMS so I dont' want to code with js an PHP div 3/4, 5/6 and 7/8 have to be wrapped with another div. So a css/js solution only please, if possible. (Thanks anyway)

Comment: yeah, so alter the news item template... you can create the same effect with hacky css, using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes, or use javascript. but trust me, it's easier to just alter the template...